# Highstock: X Axis with numeric values. Spacing not respected

Tags: highcharts, axis, numeric

For some reasons, I need to use Highstock (navigator, crosshair, annotations...).
And I need to display a graph with numerical values for X axis.
In this simple example, the X Axis looks chaotic, and numeric values are not placed/spaced as expected.

```
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    rangeSelector: {
       enabled: false
    },
    navigator:{
       enabled: true
    },
    xAxis: {
       labels: {   formatter: function () {return this.value;}},
       crosshair: {
          width: 1,
          color: 'black'
       }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'areaspline',
        data: [
            [10, 30],
            [20, 25],
            [25, 22.5],
            [30,20],
            [40,15]
        ]
    }]
});
```

JSFiddle example:
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Francois_G/5g3um6ed/)

1/ What should I do to get a graphic like this?
[Normal X axis with numerics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2AJi.png)

2/ I can see the line is smoothed. How can I disable this smoothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the `ordinal` option:

```
    xAxis: {
        ordinal: false,
        ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q6xv7koh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: Damned, I was desesperate since 2 days I'm trying to find the solution. God bless the Highstock developers to code this simple parameter. You saved my day!